# Reuse value of TensorFlow Variable between sessions without writing to disk

Tags: python, tensorflow

In sklearn, I'm used to having a model that I can run `fit` and then `predict` on. However, with TensorFlow, I'm having trouble loading the learned parameters from `fit` when I'm calling `predict`. It boils down to me not knowing how to reuse the value of a variable between sessions. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(0.0)

# fit code
with tf.Session() as sess1:
    sess1.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess1.run(tf.assign(x, 1.0)) # at end of training, x = 1.0

# predict code
with tf.Session() as sess2:
    sess2.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess2.run(x)) # want this to be 1.0, but is 0.0
```

I can think of one workaround, but it seems really hacky, and would be annoying if there are several variables I want to reuse:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(0.0)

# fit code
with tf.Session() as sess1:
    sess1.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess1.run(tf.assign(x, 1.0)) # at end of training, x = 1.0
    learned_x = sess1.run(x) # remember value of learned x at end of session

# predict code
with tf.Session() as sess2:
    sess2.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess2.run(tf.assign(x, learned_x))
    print(sess2.run(x)) # prints 1.0
```

How do I reuse variables between sessions without writing to disk (i.e. using `tf.train.Saver`)? Is the workaround I wrote above the right way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use tf.train.Saver ? That's the way models are restored and variables are reused in tensorflow. Is this more of a paradigm shift problem for you ? From sklearn to tensorflow

Comment: @ShreeshaN won't that require a disk write?

Comment: Yes it does. It serves the purpose you are looking for

Comment: @ShreeshaN Like I said in the question, I want to avoid a disk write because it's expensive and I'm doing a large hyperparameter search, so it should be parallelizable

Answer (score 2):

To mimic sklearn's model, just wrap `session` into a single class so that you can share it between methods e.g.

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = self.build_graph()
        self.session = tf.Session()
        self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    def build_graph(self):
        return {'x': tf.Variable(0.0)}

    def fit(self):
        self.session.run(tf.assign(self.graph['x'], 1.0))

    def predict(self):
        print(self.session.run(self.graph['x']))

    def close(self):
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        self.session.close()

m = Model()
m.fit()
m.predict()
m.close()
```

Make sure you close the `session` manually and handle exceptions accordingly.